# Bloomberg API pdblp/xbbg

Tags: python, bloomberg, pdblp

I am new to using Bloomberg API with wrapper `pdblp` and `xbbg`. I am trying to extract a list of members from an index, but the results obtained are only in ticker. How am I able to pull this list with the result showing in both ticker and `sedol`?

```
from xbbg import blp
index = "AS21"
index_constituents = blp.bds(index,"INDX_MWEIGHT")
```

Comment: You can try `index = "AS21 Index"`

Comment: `AS21 Index` : "Australian Stock Exchange Healthcare & Biotechnology Index
This index has been discontinued by the ASX and S&P as of the close of July 5, 2002."

Comment: As usual, the answer is in the Terminal's `FLDS` function for a given security. If you search on the field `INDX_MWEIGHT` you can see the "bulk" data: that is what `bds()` will return: no more, no less. In particular, if "Show Bulk Data..." returns an empty screen then Bloomberg has no data. With INDX_MWEIGHT you have the option to override the system default identifier, but only to get the Bloomberg id (not the SEDOL). You could make a subsequent `bdp()` call on the list of tickers to get the SEDOL, and cache the information.